# dynamic javascript with razor pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to create a model with dynamic fields... in essence, my page has a few buttons that add text boxes.

I have a variable - "counter"

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    var counter = 0;

}
```

I want to increase it everytime my button is clicked that adds a field..

```
<div class="form-group">


            <button class="control-label col-md-2" id="btnAddFieldTwo">Add Question with Multiple Answers</button>

            <div class="col-md-10">

                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <div id="fields2"></div>

                }


                <div style="color:blue"><b>Data:</b> @ViewBag.Data</div>
                <!-- JS includes -->
                <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var $fields = $('#fields2');

                    $('#btnAddFieldTwo').click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        @{ counter++ }
                        $(' <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dynamicFieldTwo">Enter the question</input><br/>@Html.TextBox("Question",@counter, new { style="color:red" }) ').appendTo($fields);
                    });
                });

                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I figured adding @{ counter++} right above the line that adds the dynamic text field would work. But the counter variable is only increased once no matter how many times I click the button. How do I increase counter every time the button is clicked ?

Comment: Your counter is server-side.  You need a *client-side* counter to increment during the client-side click events.

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: I don't have the exact code handy, but start off by taking a look at what `@Html.TextBox("Question",@counter, new { style="color:red" })` outputs in the page source.  How is the counter used in that output?  In your JavaScript code, replicate that output while incrementing the counter value.

Comment: @Html.TextBox("Question",  #HERE# , new { style="color:red" })  ---- how do I put the JavaScript variable there, it's named counter? - i put <script>
    int counter = 0;
</script> at the top of my page, and just above printing the input type I put   counter++;

Comment: You don't put a JavaScript variable there, that's C# code.  Perhaps you may need to start with some base understanding of the difference between client-side code and server-side code.  This question, though in PHP, demonstrates the concept very canonically: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/328193  The server-side language isn't important, the concept is exactly the same here.  What you need to do is entirely manipulate the page in client-side code.  So you need to start examining what your client-side code looks like.  Starting with what `@Html.TextBox()` outputs to the page.